# routeProvider and defining controllers

Tags: angularjs

How to define controllers correctly?

I want to use this form of definition:

"In a real application you should use the .controller method of your Angular Module for your application as follows:"

```
myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

my code

```
    var project = angular.module('project', [])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {controller:'Ctrl1', templateUrl:'tabb_1.html'}).
            when('/tab1', {controller:'Ctrl1', templateUrl:'tabb_1.html'}).
            when('/tab2', {controller: 'Ctrl2', templateUrl:'tabb_2.html'}).
            when('/tab3', {controller: 'Ctrl3', templateUrl:'tabb_3.html'}).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    });



project.controller('Ctrl1', '$scope', function(scope){

});

project.controller('Ctrl2','$scope', function(scope){

});

project.controller('Ctrl3', '$scope', function(scope){

});
```

i get "Error: Argument 'Ctrl1' is not a function, got string"
Where is error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example controller code is using the bracket notation for defining controllers.  This notation is useful for when you want to minimize production code, it explicitly tells angular what the dependencies it should expect are.  In your code you either need to remove the additional $scope between the name and the function or add the brackets.

No brackets:

```
project.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope){

});
```

With brackets:

```
project.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
i lost '[]'

here is the correct way

```
project.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function(scope){

}]);
```

Comment: Be careful with your scope variable in the function.  If you use bracket notation the dependencies strings you list before the function don't have to match the function parameters.  What you wrote is the same as: 
project.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function(a){}]);
Just something to be aware of.